# Just installed Ubuntu onto blank hard drive from disk but now won't boot

Tags: boot, system-installation, bios, reboot

I just installed Ubuntu onto a blank hard drive with a 10GB partition and it went fine. When I restarted the PC (when it asked), I quickly changed the BIOS so that it booted from the HDD not the disk anymore. However now all I get is a black screen with

> BOOTMGR is missing Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart

Not sure how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try re installing it again, sounds like grub got messed up... you did install grub right?

Okay this is for an older version but it is all I could find but it should give you the gist of it.

https://seogadget.co.uk/the-ubuntu-installation-guide/#Install-from-USB

Let me know if you have any more specific questions.

Comment: I didn't install grub, mostly because I have no idea what it is or how to install it ha! Any chance of home help there please?

Comment: Sure let me see if I can't dig something up...

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Well I had this problem as well. The best way to fix this error, would be to get a DVD-R or DVD-RW, download>install Ubuntu 12.04, whatever processor, let it be 64 bit or 32 bit. Then download a really good ISO creator like pen drive Linux or you can use Window's ISO creator, this is a good way as well. The hardware has to be removed the secondary memory. This is the hard drive, the windows one take it out, no more windows HDD. Then hook up the new/used hard drive and properly hook up all the connections that are going to be used. Restart the computer, then put in the DVD, DVD-RW. Put in the DVD. Turn on the computer, press the get to BIOS screen, and at the same time open up the drivd.
Best of Luck
Sincerily Ronnie

Answer (score 0):

Grub 2 is the default boot manager for Ubuntu and it would appear it was not installed properly during your Ubuntu install process.

There are ways to repair Grub but since this is a fresh install your best bet is to do a full reinstall.

At some point during the install process you will be asked "Would you like to write Grub to the master boot record?" or something along those lines. You should answer Yes to this and Grub should be installed properly.